# Am I exempted if I take this student loan involving riba?

Tags: fiqh, riba, fatwa, loan, studying

I've been working really hard in high school to get accepted to a good major in university. I'm going to start studying this summer. I need an apartment and food to live and I have no income what's so ever. The only income I can get is if I take a student loan. But the thing is, there's a 0,05 interest rate which is little but its still RIBA.

If I don't take it I have to live on the streets while studying for 3 years. The thing is, I can get a job on the weekends but it will not give me enough for residence and other necessities. You may think that I can work at night on normal days but if I do that I will literally get no sleep (maybe a couple hours if I end school and studying early).

I don't know what to do and I'm so done with life. Is this really a necessity so that I'm exempted and forgiven for this sin?

Answer (score 1):

> "O believers! Do not consume interest, multiplying it many times over. And be mindful of Allah, so you may prosper." 
>  -Qur'an 3:130

> "and for their charging Ribā (usury or interest) while they were
> forbidden from it, and for their devouring of the properties of the
> people by false means. We have prepared, for the disbelievers among
> them, a painful punishment." 
>  -Qur'an 4:161

> "Whatever you lend out in usury to gain value through other people’s
> wealth will not increase in God’s eyes, but whatever you give in
> charity, in your desire for God’s approval, will earn multiple
> rewards." 
>  Qur'an 30:39

> "Those who consume interest cannot stand [on the Day of Resurrection]
> except as one stands who is being beaten by Satan into insanity. That
> is because they say, "Trade is [just] like interest." But Allah has
> permitted trade and has forbidden interest. So whoever has received an
> admonition from his Lord and desists may have what is past, and his
> affair rests with Allah . But whoever returns to [dealing in interest
> or usury] - those are the companions of the Fire; they will abide
> eternally therein. Allah destroys interest and gives increase for
> charities. And Allah does not like every sinning disbeliever. Indeed,
> those who believe and do righteous deeds and establish prayer and give
> zakah will have their reward with their Lord, and there will be no
> fear concerning them, nor will they grieve. O you who have believed,
> fear Allah and give up what remains [due to you] of interest, if you
> should be believers. And if you do not, then be informed of a war
> [against you] from Allah and His Messenger. But if you repent, you may
> have your principal - [thus] you do no wrong, nor are you wronged."
>
>  Qur'an 2:275-280

> The Messenger of Allah (saws) cursed the one who consumed Riba, and
> the oe who charged it, those who witnessed it, and the one who
> recorded it. 
>  -Jami At-Tirmidhi 1206

Riba is a major sin in Islam. No questions asked. You must do everything in your willpower to not enter interest. You must not engage in it, even if you're at the risk of homelessness. Insha'Allah, Allah will see how you're staying clear from such a major sin, He will aid you and grant you fortune. Keep making Dua.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. But if starve to death or die of nutrition deficiency because I avoided riba, will I be a martyr?